# SQL database in Google Cloud, insert data with curl

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

I have created a MySQL database in google cloud. I want to insert/update/delete data with curl from the command line. Is there any google api with which you can do this without creating your own API to do this ?

Or is there any other simple and pretty much out-of-the-box solution for this. I just want to spin up a database to insert some data for my project and not spend a lot of time creating the api

-Jani

Comment: Why do you want to use cURL for that? There's a native MySQL shell client which can do all that

Comment: I am going to use it from a bash script so it would be easier to just use curl. I think I will use Firestore instead: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL client protocol is not HTTP, therefore you cannot use an HTTP tool such as `curl` to communicate with MySQL unless you install a bridge/translation library.

The out of the box solution is to use the MySQL client library.